# Are multiple-table DELETE statements bad practice? Why?

Tags: mysql, myisam, sql-delete

I'm working with a MySQL database that uses the MyISAM storage engine. I make use of the multiple-table delete syntax. So far, I've only used it when I need to delete from multiple child tables at once. But I was considering using it to delete from multiple child tables *and* the parent table in one query.

Recently, I've come across a couple of posts on SO and other forums that say that it's a bad idea to delete from multiple tables at once. But none of the posters explain *why* it's not recommended.

I understand that there can be problems with multiple-table deletes involving InnoDB tables with foreign key constraints because you can't control the order the tables are processed in. Obviously, that is not an issue in my case.

I had thought that a multiple-table delete would delete from all tables or none. But I can't find information of whether that is true or not. If it can partially succeed, that would corrupt the data.

Is it a bad idea to delete from multiple MyISAM tables at once? Is it always a bad idea or only when it involves a parent/child relationship? Please explain why.

For the record, changing to InnoDB is not an option for this project at this time.

Comment: Do you delete or drop the table per se or you were referring to the records of these tables (parent and child)?

Comment: I was referring to records in the tables.

Answer (score 1):

One possible problem that I could see is that if it there is a glitch (like a server breakdown, power outage etc) and you already deleted the parent records (from the parent table) before the related child record(s) then you have what is known as `orphan record(s)` meaning the related child record/table could no longer be related to a mother record/table. Although this could overcome if you delete first the child table/record before the parent table/record.

Another one is `performance issue` since `MyISAM` uses table-level locking so deleting multiple records (from multiple tables) has bigger chance of degrading the access time performance than say deleting from few sources.